# How does full_line works in SublimeText?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I'm trying to mimick `view.full_line` SublimeText function using python, if we read the [docs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) we'll see:

> line(point): Returns the line that contains the point.
>
> line(region): Returns a modified copy of region such that it starts at the beginning of a line, and ends at the end of a line. Note that it may span several lines.
>
> full_line(point): As line(), but the region includes the trailing newline character, if any.
>
> full_line(region): As line(), but the region includes the trailing newline character, if any.

I've tried to follow the explanation from that docs and here's what I've got:

```
class Region(object):
    __slots__ = ['a', 'b', 'xpos']

    def __init__(self, a, b=None, xpos=-1):
        if b is None:
            b = a
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.xpos = xpos

    def __str__(self):
        return "(" + str(self.a) + ", " + str(self.b) + ")"

    def __repr__(self):
        return "(" + str(self.a) + ", " + str(self.b) + ")"

    def begin(self):
        if self.a < self.b:
            return self.a
        else:
            return self.b

    def end(self):
        if self.a < self.b:
            return self.b
        else:
            return self.a


def lskip_nonewlines(text, pt):
    len_text = len(text)

    while True:
        if pt <= 0 or pt >= len_text:
            break
        if text[pt - 1] == "\n" or text[pt] == "\n":
            break
        pt -= 1

    return pt


def rskip_nonewlines(text, pt):
    len_text = len(text)

    while True:
        if pt <= 0 or pt >= len_text:
            break
        if text[pt] == "\n":
            break
        pt += 1

    return pt


def full_line(text, x):
    region = Region(x)

    if region.a <= region.b:
        # try:
        #     if text[region.a]=="\n":
        #         region.a-=1
        # except Exception as e:
        #     pass

        region.a = lskip_nonewlines(text, region.a)
        region.b = rskip_nonewlines(text, region.b)
        region.b = region.b + 1 if region.b < len(text) else region.b
    else:
        region.a = rskip_nonewlines(text, region.a)
        region.b = lskip_nonewlines(text, region.b)
        region.a = region.a + 1 if region.a < len(text) else region.a

    return (region.begin(), region.end())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = "# I'm a comment\n\n\ndef foo():\n    print('# No comment')\n"
    sublime_output = [
        [0, (0, 16)],
        [1, (0, 16)],
        [2, (0, 16)],
        [3, (0, 16)],
        [4, (0, 16)],
        [5, (0, 16)],
        [6, (0, 16)],
        [7, (0, 16)],
        [8, (0, 16)],
        [9, (0, 16)],
        [10, (0, 16)],
        [11, (0, 16)],
        [12, (0, 16)],
        [13, (0, 16)],
        [14, (0, 16)],
        [15, (0, 16)],
        [16, (16, 17)],
        [17, (17, 18)],
        [18, (18, 29)],
        [19, (18, 29)],
        [20, (18, 29)],
        [21, (18, 29)],
        [22, (18, 29)],
        [23, (18, 29)],
        [24, (18, 29)],
        [25, (18, 29)],
        [26, (18, 29)],
        [27, (18, 29)],
        [28, (18, 29)],
        [29, (29, 55)],
        [30, (29, 55)],
        [31, (29, 55)],
        [32, (29, 55)],
        [33, (29, 55)],
        [34, (29, 55)],
        [35, (29, 55)],
        [36, (29, 55)],
        [37, (29, 55)],
        [38, (29, 55)],
        [39, (29, 55)],
        [40, (29, 55)],
        [41, (29, 55)],
        [42, (29, 55)],
        [43, (29, 55)],
        [44, (29, 55)],
        [45, (29, 55)],
        [46, (29, 55)],
        [47, (29, 55)],
        [48, (29, 55)],
        [49, (29, 55)],
        [50, (29, 55)],
        [51, (29, 55)],
        [52, (29, 55)],
        [53, (29, 55)],
        [54, (29, 55)],
    ]

    for test in sublime_output:
        pos, expected_output = test
        output = full_line(text, pos)

        try:
            assert output == expected_output
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error at pos: {pos}, output {output}, expected output {expected_output}")
```

The above mcve is comparing the output with results I've got from SublimeText itself. You can see like the function behaves quite well but it will still fail in some corner cases:

```
Error at pos: 0, output (0, 1), expected output (0, 16)
Error at pos: 15, output (15, 16), expected output (0, 16)
Error at pos: 28, output (28, 29), expected output (18, 29)
Error at pos: 54, output (54, 55), expected output (29, 55)
```

So, how can I fix the routine so it'll behave 1:1 like SublimeText's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of fairly obvious bugs in your code that's stopping it from doing what you want it to.

```
Error at pos: 0, output (0, 1), expected output (0, 16)
```

This looks like an indication that when the code is scanning forward from position 0 to determine where the line ends, it's stopping at position 1 instead of position 16.

So looking at your code, you have this bit here; it's the upper portion of the `if` because your test regions are always made in a way where `a == b`:

```py
        region.a = lskip_nonewlines(text, region.a)
        region.b = rskip_nonewlines(text, region.b)
        region.b = region.b + 1 if region.b < len(text) else region.b
```

So looking at this, finding the end position is the job of `rskip_nonewlines()`, and then so long as the returned region is smaller than the text we bump up by one. One can thus infer that this method is intended to return the location of a found `newline` character:

```py
def rskip_nonewlines(text, pt):
    len_text = len(text)

    while True:
        if pt <= 0 or pt >= len_text:
            break
        if text[pt] == "\n":
            break
        pt += 1

    return pt
```

When you invoke this with a `pt` of 0, the first thing it does is determine that `0 <= 0` evaluates to `True` which breaks it out of the `while` loop and causes it to immediately return back `0`. Then, since 0 is smaller than the text, it adds `1`, and you get an ultimate result of `(0, 1)`.

If you remove the `pt <= 0 or` part of your conditional statement, it will correctly locate the newline at position `15`, add `1` to it, and end you at `(0, 16)` as it should. It looks like this is a copy/paste error from `lskip_nonewlines()` perhaps.

```
Error at pos: 15, output (15, 16), expected output (0, 16)
```

This looks like an indication that when the code is scanning backward from position 15 to determine where this line starts, it's stopping at position 15 instead of at position 0.

Again based on the above code, it's the job of `lskip_nonewlines()` to find the start of the line:

```py
def lskip_nonewlines(text, pt):
    len_text = len(text)

    while True:
        if pt <= 0 or pt >= len_text:
            break
        if text[pt - 1] == "\n" or text[pt] == "\n":
            break
        pt -= 1

    return pt
```

In this loop, we first make sure we're not going to run off the ends of the string, then we check to see if the character prior to `pt` or the character at `pt` is a newline.

We already know from the previous example that position `15` is a `newline` character, so here on the first iteration through the loop we immediately find that we're on a newline and return `pt` back untouched. giving an ultimate result of `(15, 16)`.

In this case, removing `or text[pt] == "\n"` from the conditional stops it from immediately determining that the line ends where it started and allows it to scan backward to position 0 before deciding to stop, which gives you the desired `(0, 16)` return.

With those two changes made, your test program doesn't generate any errors.